# Returning NSWindow/ AXUIElement using its pid_t

Tags: cocoa

Is it possible to get a AXUIElementRef of an open application knowing its PID?

My project is opening a file/folder. Then I get its PID and I want to be able to get access to this open window, so that is why I want AXUIElementRef of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extern AXUIElementRef AXUIElementCreateApplication ( pid_t pid);`

> Creates and returns the top-level accessibility object for the application with the specified process ID.

[AXUIElementCreateApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ApplicationServices/Reference/AXUIElement_header_reference/#//apple_ref/c/func/AXUIElementCreateApplication)

Comment: Thanks for this, I've found it and was trying to use it but it didn't work. What I did wrong - I wrote AXUIElementCreateApplication(myPid) as! AXUIElementRef, and I got an error. In order to get an AXUIElement I had to just simply add .takeRetainedValue to my constant.

Comment: As we are here. Any idea how to get NSURL of an application that is set as default for opening a file at specified path/ url?

Comment: Try `NSWorkspace`'s `URLForApplicationToOpenURL:`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution as below in Swift 5

```
    let applicationRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid)
    
    var uiElementsValue: AnyObject?
    
    AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(applicationRef, kAXWindowsAttribute as CFString, &uiElementsValue)
    
    guard let appElements = uiElementsValue as? [AXUIElement] else { return }
```

'appElements' are your opening windows.